# Which website builders allow for formatting code in blogs?

Tags: code-beautification

I built a website using Wix, which also allows for creating a blog within the website.  Much of my blogging is about various programming issues and highlights sections of code.  Unfortunately, Wix does not allow any type of code formatting (aka beautification) within a blog. I am after the type of formatting you see in the screenshot ([source](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/52224-find-a-file-given-a-search-path/)). I am wondering what my options are here. Are there any website builders out there that allow code formatting within blogs? As an alternative, perhaps I can link a blog feed to my Wix site?

[image]

Comment: Have you looked into WordPress?

Comment: I have no experience using Wix before. So, I come here asking for a question. Can you edit your blog post source code?

If you can, there are lot of syntax highlighter out there. For instance, [Github Gist](https://gist.github.com). You can embed it into your blog post.